# É possível gerar um executável no Android Studio?

Tags: java, android

Olá, quero rodar minha aplicação Android no PC (Windows) sem emulador, para seja possível instalar com .exe, isso é possível?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/?hl=pt-br

Comment: Eu  preciso de um .exe para produção. obrigado.

Comment: Vai precisar do emulador... não tem jeito, o windows não irá interpretar instruções que são para outro SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Infelizmente, até onde sei, não é possível.

Quando você compila o seu código, ele gera um bytecode que roda em uma JVM, mas essa JVM é dedicada ao sistema android. De toda forma você precisa de um emulador para simular recursos como GPS, Rede, sistema de arquivos e câmera.

Comment: Obrigado @Renato Tavares é bastante esclarecedora a sua resposta, vou aguardar um pouco mais antes de validar isso.

Answer (score 1):

Com certeza não, windows e android são duas plataformas distintas com duas arquiteturas diferentes, assim como um código para o android não vai ser executado no windows, um programa executável não vai executar no android, então a única forma de executar uma aplicação android no windows é através de um emulador, se você precisa de um emulador para produção recomendo o [BlueStacks](https://www.bluestacks.com/pt-br).